# jquery calendar

Tags: jquery, calendar

i use jquery calendar in a page. i used a common settings for all the dates such as dob, date of join, married date, order date etc. Now i want to set some additional settings for some dates, such as dob should not take future value. So i want to use the general settings and additional seetings. I keep the general settings in a common file. How do I add additional settings in each page.
thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider the [Validation plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validate).

It will give you 4 new validations:

- dpDate - basic format validation
- dpMinDate - validation against a minimum date limit only
- dpMaxDate - validation against a maximum date limit only
- dpMinMaxDate - validation against minimum and maximum date limit

You can see a demonstration of how this will work with the jQuery DatePicker [here](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html) (click the Validation tab).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code...

```
$('#<%=txtDate.ClientID%>').change(function() {
                    var date = $(this).val();
               var arrDate = date .split("/");
var today=new Date();
var useDate = new Date(arrDate[2], arrDate[1]-1, arrDate[0]); 

                   if(useDate>today){
                     showStatus(true, 'Your Message Here');
  $('#<%=txtDate.ClientID%>').val('');
   }
                    });
```